# How to forced focusing on child form?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

How to force fully focus child form when we click on client area of it's parent form?  [Like MessageBox or Error message have such focus so we must click on Ok button of messagebox.]

This is my code:

```
form = new Form2(); 
form.MdiParent = this; 
form.ShowDialog(ParentForm);
```

But it gives me the error:

> Form that is not a top-level form cannot be displayed as a modal
>   dialog box. Remove the form from any parent form before calling
>   showDialog.

Comment: Can you show a code example of your attempts accomplishing this?

Comment: I use TopMost = true but that is not what i want.

Answer (score 1):

Original answer - for non-MDIChild
Make the child form modal using the ShowDialog method.

```
ChildForm.ShowDialog (ParentForm);
```

To keep an MDI Child form at the top:
Handle the MDIChildActivate event on the parent form, and in that, set the child form that you want to stay visible to be active:. In this example, Form2 is the modal form, and Form3 is another form for testing.

```
private Form2 frm2;
private Form3 frm3;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frm2=new Form2();
    frm2.MdiParent=this ;
    frm2.Show();

    frm3= new Form3() ;
    frm3.MdiParent=this;
    frm3.Show();
}

private void Form1_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        frm2.Activate();
}
```

Comment: i try this but this is working only when i remove parent form.

Comment: When use this with parent form it give me error : Form that is not a top-level form cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Remove the form from any parent form before calling showDialog.

Comment: form = new Form2();                
form.MdiParent = this;
form.ShowDialog(ParentForm); This my code.

Comment: You can't use showDialog on MDI child forms. You could make form not an MDI child form by not setting the Mdiparent.

Comment: So is there any way for MiDiparent form so i can focus child form?

Comment: using `Activate()` seems to do the trick but the `effect` is not like a `Dialog`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have some kind of `MessageBox` in the `MDI Parent Form` with `TopLevel = false`. To make the effect look like the real effect a window shown by `ShowDialog()` has, I think this is the only solution which requires you to create a custom Form for your `MDI child form`:

```
public class ChildForm : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern int FlashWindowEx(FLASHWINFO flashInfo);
    struct FLASHWINFO
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public IntPtr hwnd;
        public uint flags;
        public int count;
        public int timeOut;
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {            
        if (ParentForm != null)
        {                
            ChildForm dialog = ((Form1)ParentForm).Dialog;
            if (dialog != this && dialog!=null)
            {                    
                if (m.Msg == 0x84) //WM_NCHITTEST
                {
                    if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
                    {
                        Flash(dialog.Handle);
                    }
                    return;
                }                    
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    private void Flash(IntPtr handle)
    {
        FLASHWINFO flashInfo = new FLASHWINFO()
        {
            hwnd = handle,
            count = 9,
            cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(FLASHWINFO)),
            flags = 3,
            timeOut = 50
        };
        FlashWindowEx(flashInfo); 
    }
    public void Flash()
    {
        Flash(Handle);
    }
    //This is to disable Tab when the Dialog is shown
    protected override bool ProcessTabKey(bool forward)
    {
        if(((Form1)ParentForm).Dialog == this) return true;
        return base.ProcessTabKey(forward);
    }
}
//Here is your MDI parent form
public class Form1 : Form {
   public Form1(){
       InitializeComponent();
       IsMdiContainer = true;
       f1 = new ChildForm();
       f2 = new ChildForm();
       f1.MdiParent = this;
       f2.MdiParent = this;
       //Get MDI Client
       foreach(Control c in Controls){
          if(c is MdiClient){
               client = c;
               break;
          }
       }
       client.Click += ClientClicked;           
   }
   ChildForm f1, f2; 
   MdiClient client;
   public ChildForm Dialog {get;set;}
   private void ClientClicked(object sender, EventArgs e){
       if(Dialog != null) Dialog.Flash();
       else {//Show dialog, you can show dialog in another event handler, this is for demonstrative purpose
           Dialog = new ChildForm(){MdiParent = this, Visible = true};
           ActivateMdiChild(Dialog);
           //Suppose clicking on the Dialog client area will close the dialog
           Dialog.Click += (s,ev) => {
              Dialog.Close();
           };
           Dialog.FormClosed += (s,ev) => {
              Dialog = null;
           };
       }
   }
}
```